# Mobile broadband Internet connection established but unable to browse and download

Tags: internet, internet-connection, mobile-broadband

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and mobile GSM universal modem for Internet connection in my acer netbook (without cdrom). The connection is established but I am unable to browse the Internet and download updates. Can any one help?

It is working in my Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Try disconnecting the network and reconnect it

Comment: Enter this command in terminal and say what you get : **ping www.google.com**

Comment: Did you use the correct APN settings?

Comment: @Arun Please check your network signal strength and also be aware that 2G network is much slower compared to 3G network. And also some time it shows connection established but still it doesn't let you browse anything try to check with other network.

Comment: @Namshum 2G network is slower but not that slower. Also he said, the connection is already established

Comment: What DNS server have you set? You may need to set network settings manually.

Comment: Yes, Anwar 2G network sometime becomes very pathetic to use. It allows connection to be established but doesn't let you to browse anything.

Comment: Contact your ISP

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure whether you are using a static IP or getting from the DHCP(Mobile Broadband)

use  `cat /var/log/syslog` and check for something like below..

```
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPOFFER from 10.100.1.254
DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK from 10.100.1.254
```

if you have something similar to above then you are using DHCP else you've a IP address configured and need to remove it.

I think you also need to check whether you are getting the correct IP address, to do this use.

```
ifconfig
```

to check the Gateway use

```
route -en
```

then **ping** to the **gateway IP address** to check the connectivity if everything is fine then you should be able to ping to your gateway IP address.